# AttributeError : buffer

Tags: python

I keep getting this attribute error when I use -

```
a,b=map(int,sys.stdin.buffer.read().split())
```

while,

```
a,b=(int(x) for x in input().split())
```

works fine.

Also is there a faster way to do input output operations in python??

Comment: What makes you think `sys.stdin` has a `buffer` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to read one line from stdin and parse it into ints is as follows:

```
# Python 2
list_of_ints = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]

# Python 3
list_of_ints = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Alternately, you may use `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input` / `raw_input`. File-like objects in Python (including standard in/out/error) do not have, and never had, a `buffer` attribute.